# Assembly programming infinite loop problem

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to run an assembly language program but it is creating an infinite loop:

```
0040:0010   AAM ???
042F:03A2   MOV WORD PTR CS:
            [0088],0005
042F:03A9   JMP 03F1
042F:03F1   CLI
042F:03F2   DEC BYTE PTR CS:
            [008E]
```

after last instruction the control again transfer to 0040:0010

Comment: That's your complete program? What is its purpose?

Comment: No this is not the complete program, actually this is MS -DOS source code github program, when I run the stddos.asm file it calls for msdos.asm file, this code actually exists in MS-DOS source code. When I run the exe file after "ml stddos.asm" in the cmd, then it shows NTVDM system memory violation error. When I debug using CV Code Viewer then the program caught in above given infinite loop.

Comment: I don't see what role `0040:0010` plays in this. Even if control goes there (which it shouldn't) that's not code, it's the BIOS data area. `AAM` won't continue at `042F:03A2` so there can't be a loop. Also, running this under windows might not be the best idea. Use a bare metal virtual machine.

Comment: I'm debugging it using code viewer CV in dosbox, where this loop is occurring.